# junit duplicate key, but first three times

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, junit

I run junit tests, with almost the same configuration like main project, in postgres like a main project but on separate test db. Every run i insert prepared data for test.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlb92.jpg"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlb92.jpg%22)
I test service method "addCategory" and three times run i get "duplicate key value violates unique constraint "category_pkey"". the fourth time the entity gets id=4 and all right. I try different generic strategy but problem not solved

How do that test work on first run?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit easier with code, but overall after manual insertion you should let Hibernate know what is the next id.
E.g. for sequence-based you should either:

1. not use defined Ids in insertion script and specify Ids using `nextval()` function OR
2. manually update next sequence value: `alter sequence OBJECT_SEQ restart start with 4;`